# Managing session and request attributes in Servlet

Tags: java, jsp

I have a very simple JSP page where it has one search box and based off the input, in the search box, it will return a response with a submit button to get the following response.

---

I noticed that whenever I use `request.getattribute("foo")` in my servlet to retrieve some request it returns null due to the request ending so I looked at the answers on here and started using `session.getattribute("foo")` instead. However, now I am stuck having session variables responses being set and it is causing my view to have old session data that isn't suppose to be there so now I have to use `session.removeAttribute("foo")`, whenever, I don't want that particular response data to be shown.

---

Is there a better way to go about managing this instead of having to use `session.getattribute("foo")`, `session.removeAttribute("foo")` and `session.setattribute("foo")`?

Answer (score 1):

You should work with [request.getSession()](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession())

> Returns the current session associated with this request, or if the request does not have a session, creates one.

Set an attribute:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("foo")
```

And get attribute using:

```
request.getSession().getAttribute("foo")
```

It will be used in the context of the request and not effect other requests, so you don't need to remove attribute.

Read more in [Servlets tutorial](http://web.cs.ucla.edu/classes/winter15/cs144/projects/java/session/index.html)

> Servlets provide an outstanding technical solution: the HttpSession API. This is a high-level interface that allows the server to "remember" a set of information relevant to a particular user's on-going transaction, so that it can retrieve this information to handle any future requests from the same user.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for `request.getparameter("foo")` or `request.setparameter("foo", obj)`

This can be used for every request, and it will not add to your session variables and basically will not make your "session object heavy".

[Java doc:](http://%20%20https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameter%28java.lang.String%29)

> Request parameters are extra information sent with the request. For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or posted form data.

Comment: But I already said that i used request.getparameter before and it returns null since the request has ended

Comment: @Robin wait you mentioned `getattribute` not `getparameter`

Comment: using `request.getSession().setAttribute("foo")` is bad as it will slow your application as session object grows.

Comment: But request.getparameter returns String objects whereas I want a Java Object to be returned

Comment: Sure, did I missed that part of your question that you need Java object? If that is the case go for the session object.